# Checking if an organizationalUnit exists by it's DN. (LDAP, Bash)

Tags: bash, search, ldap, dn

I want to check in a bash script that a specific organizationalunit with the given DN exists.

I'm doing an ldapsearch:

```
OU="ou=HQ,dc=myroot,dc=local"

ldapsearch -h localhost -b dc=myroot,dc=local -x -v "(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(dn="'"'$OU'"'"))"
```

and it always results in 0 even if the DN exists.

I have also tried:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -b dc=myroot,dc=local -x -v "(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(dn=$OU))"
```

But the results are the same.

How can I do it? Is there a trick to the dn attribute?

Disregard that I'm using simple authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put the DN inside the search filter because the DN is not an attribute name.
Put your dn as the search base (ldapsearch -b) and the objectclass into the search filter.
Something like this:

```
OU='ou=HQ,dc=myroot,dc=local'
ldapsearch -h localhost -b "$OU" -x -v -D'cn=admin,dc=myroot,dc=local' -wyour_ldap_password '(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit))'
```

And you'll be fine.